# Check if value already exists while typing?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In Meteor, what is the most efficient way to check the database to see if something exists while the user is typing?

For example, I'm trying to check if the username exists in database while the user is typing his/her desired name to register an account.

I could create a keydown event to check every time when there's a key stroke, or I could use `setInterval`, but I feel like that's an overkill.

Is there a built in method in Meteor to do something like this?

Comment: I usually do it when the input looses focus.

Comment: I'm using `Collection.find({value: {$regex: your_input.value}});` as a query and it's working pretty well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did't see anything like that, so you'll have to built it yourself.

**Security**

Showing which usernames are taken while typing makes it very easy to retrieve a list of existing users. This could be okay if the user list is available to public anyway (for example in a forum), but in most applications you should avoid that.

**Waiting until user stops typing**

Users probably type faster than the service is able to check the database. Therefore checking on every key stroke would cause a lot of unnecessary service calls. You should at least implement a delay or wait until the field looses focus.

**Forseeing next character**

You should try to minimize service calls. For example if someone types "Mic", besides checking the exact name, you could add that "Mick" and "Mic1" are already taken too. Further optimization would be to predict more than one character based on common names, but that probably will never be needed.

**Reusing Autocomplete Code**

You could reuse some code of a autocomplete component, for example when to trigger a service call. But most of the code you can't reuse, because the user interface is very different.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this smart package useful.

https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-autocomplete